# Fill intersection area of objects

Tags: java, android, user-interface, canvas, android-canvas

I want to fill the intersection area of a rectangle and a circle using Android Canvas like in the image below:

[image: Circle and rectangle, intersection area is colored purple]

How can I achieve this?

**Update :** 
here my code

```
public static class MyView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(getRect(), paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawCircle(250,150, 100, paint);
    }

    public Rect getRect() {
        return new Rect(100,100,400,200);
    }

}
```

Now :

[image: what i get]

in this case, The Wanted result is this :

[image: Wanted result]

Thanks for any help

Comment: What have your tried so far? People are here to help out, not to write your code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the `android.graphics.Path` class.

If you can define your shapes with `Path`s, then you can draw them using `canvas.drawPath()`.

`Path` has a method called `op()` that you can use to get the intersection of two paths, like this:

```
    Path square = ...
    Path circle = ...
    Path intersect = circle.op(square, Op.INTERSECT);
```

With a `Paint.Style` of `FILL`, you can color the intersection of the two shapes.