# Custom background with inset rounded border

Tags: android, android-layout, background

Is it possible to create, in Android, the white translucent background like the one in the following image? Thank you!

[image: Custom rounded border]

Comment: you can get an idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370178/fill-intersection-area-of-objects

Comment: What are you calling the background? Is it the blurred image behind the notch that says "Fratelli Club" or is it the translucent white background of the notch. Maybe both?

Comment: I am referring to the white translucent background with rounded borders.

Answer (score 0):

Transparency color code is :

> `#80FFFFFF`

Add this at your TextView "Fratelli Club" and play with the percentage of the transparency.

Comment: And the rounded borders?

Comment: as far as i know you can't create a 2way up rounded in a different way. You can make the textview in a round way like for example let's say it's a button.
Or if you want it to look a like work on the image via Photoshop then.. and use guidelines for the textview to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Try this shape file for round corners on the bottom only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
<solid
    android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

</shape>
```